# How to render GIF animations in urxvt in order to integrate animated previews in ranger?

Tags: gif, xorg, rxvt, w3m

Ranger optionally uses the w3mimgdisplay binary in order to display [image previews in the terminal](http://blog.z3bra.org/2014/01/images-in-terminal.html). Similarly I would like animated gifs to be animated in ranger's preview area. I've been testing in urxvt:

```
#! /bin/bash
clear
gifsicle -e $1
for f in *.gif.*
 do
  sleep .05s
  echo -e "0;1;0;0;200;160;;;;;$f\n4;\n3;" | /usr/lib/w3m/w3mimgdisplay
  rm $f
done
clear
```

But that's ugly I know. I'd much rather choose the window id for gifview like `gifview -w 0x360000b -a some.gif` but weird stuff happens with the urxvt background and I want to be able to have ranger control the width and position. The preview should be scalable and auto-repeating. If the original frame rate is sacrificed, so be it.